# SQLite in memory with dapper generates non-existent table error

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, dapper

I have the following code for creating the table:

```
string query = @"CREATE TABLE GVP_USERS_TAGS(
                        ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                        DATEINS datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT DATETIME('now'),
                        NAME varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                        OWNER integer NOT NULL,
                        USER_ID integer NOT NULL,
                        PRODUCT_ID integer NOT NULL,
                        TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL,
                        VALUE varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                        PRODUCT_TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL,
                        Updated_Row timestamp NOT NULL,
                        MOVIE_TYPE_ID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                        PIN_REQUIRED integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
                    )";
    return await queryExecutor.ExecuteAsync(query);
```

then use the following code:

```
var countQuery = $"SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM GVP_USERS_TAGS NOLOCK {where}";
int count = await queryExecutor.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(countQuery, parameters);
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
SQL logic error\\r\\nno such table: GVP_USERS_TAGS\
```

detail when using in filesystem works.

Comment: What exactly is `where`?

Comment: @CL. `WHERE USER_ID = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve using `_connection.Open();`